# PHP, MYSQL, phpmyadmin - Using a html form to input records to a database

Tags: php, mysql, database

My objective is to have two separate php pages.One page is for a user to input data into form fields (first name, last name, product, size), and the other is to display the updated table (after the user submits their fields).
So far, I have created the two pages, with a functional form and a page that displays my tables results. Here is my code:

Form.php

```
<form action="process.php" method="post">
<p>
First Name:<input type="text" name="first_name"><br>
Last Name:<input type="text" name="last_name"><br>
Product:<input type="text" name="product"><br>
Size:<input type="text" name="size"><br>
</p>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

<?php
if (isset($POST['submit'])) {
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
if (!$con){
die("Connection was not successful:" . mysql_error());      
}
mysql_select_db("database_name",$con);

$sql = "INSERT INTO Order_1 (First_Name, Last_Name, Product, Size) VALUES ('$_POST[first_name]','$_POST[last_name]','$_POST[product]','$_POST[size]')";


$myData = mysql_query($sql,$con);

mysql_close($con);
}
?>
```

And here is my results.php page, which displays my table:

```
<?php   

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
if (!$con){
die("Connection was not successful:" . mysql_error());      
}
mysql_select_db("database name",$con);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Order_1";
$myData = mysql_query($sql,$con);
echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>First Name</th>
<th>Last Name</th>
<th>Product</th>
<th>Size</th>
</tr>";

while($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData)){
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $record['First Name'] . "</td>"; 
echo "<td>" . $record['Last Name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $record['Product'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $record['Size'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo"</table>";
mysql_close($con);

?>
```

I currently have two records in my table, that I manually typed into phpmyadmin. When i fill out this form, and click submit, it takes me to the "process.php" but nothing has changed. It's still only displaying the two records I have. And inside my PHPmyAdmin, it only has those two records. So my form isn't working how i'd like -- inputting a record submitted from the form, from a user, and displaying the entire table, included the record just recorded from the user, on the "process.php" code.
I have gone over my code for (oh my god its been 4 hours now) and I can't find the solution. I've tested numerous things. Can anyone help? It'd be much appreciated.

Comment: You should note that the mysql extension has been removed entirely from PHP 7, so you really should be learning PDO instead for entering form data into a database. If you are using PHP 5 the mysql extension will work but you are spending time learning obsolete technology.

Answer (score -1):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Order_1 (First_Name, Last_Name, Product, Size) VALUES ('".$_POST[first_name]."','".$_POST[last_name]."','".$_POST[product]."','".$_POST[size]."')";
```

You forgot to concatenate the variable inside your query that is why it is not inserting.